# Sharing a @StateObject between iOS and macOS views which are not set up in my App protocol implementation

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to make a multiplatform SwiftUI application that would run on iOS and macOS. On the last one, I would like the app to be visible only as a menu bar item (no Dock icon, no windows).

I decided to have two views:

- `MacSampleView()` which is used on a macOS status bar popover via custom `NSApplicationDelegate`
- `SampleView()` for iOS and other Apple platforms via traditional `WindowGroup` scene

In my implementation of the `App` I have the app delegate inside `#if os(macOS)` compiler directive to use it only on macOS.

All was good until I decided to have a `@StateObject var configuration` which I would like to share between platforms.

I have no trouble passing it as `.environmentObject(configuration)` to `SampleView()` in my `WindowGroup`, but when I want to pass it to the `MacSampleView()` which is created inside my `NSApplicationDelegate` — I simply can't access it there.

I'm new to Apple platforms programming and it feels like I'm wrong somewhere on the conceptual level, so appreciate any help with that.

```swift
@main
struct SampleApp: App {

    @StateObject var configuration = Config()
    
    #if os(macOS)
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    #endif

    var body: some Scene {
        #if os(macOS)
        Settings {
            EmptyView()
        }
        #else
        WindowGroup {
            SampleView().environmentObject(configuration)
        }
        #endif
}
```

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // I struggle here! I want to pass `@StateObject var configuration` from the `SampleApp` to the `MacSampleView()` somehow.
        // It's not possible to simply call `.environmentObject(configuration)` because `configuration` is unavailable in the delegate.
        let macSampleView = MacSampleView()

        let popover = NSPopover()
        // ...
        popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: macSampleView)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just inject a different instance into the environment in your app delegate.  You don't need to use @StateObject here either.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was following Apple's [Managing Model Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app#Share-an-Object-Throughout-Your-App) tutorial which has `@StateObject` in code sample. So you say I may have something like:
`class Config : ObservableObject { static let shared = Config() }` and pass `.environmentObject(Config.shared)` instead?
Are there some limitations related to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `Config` is app-wide level single instance you can use shared object for both cases, like

```
class Config: ObservableObject {
   static let shared = Config()       // << this one !!

   // .. other code
}

@main
struct SampleApp: App {

    @StateObject var configuration = Config.shared    // << here !!
    
    #if os(macOS)
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    #endif

    var body: some Scene {
        #if os(macOS)
        Settings {
            EmptyView()
        }
        #else
        WindowGroup {
            SampleView().environmentObject(configuration)
        }
        #endif
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let macSampleView = MacSampleView()
             .environmentObject(Config.shared)  // << same instance !!
        let popover = NSPopover()
        // ...
        popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: macSampleView)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: With that, I probably don't even need `@StateObject var configuration` at all?
I may pass `Config.shared` to `SampleView()` as well.

Comment: I don't see all your code, but yes it is possible.