# Cannot inject AppDelegate to SwiftUI macos app

Tags: swift, swiftui, appdelegate, appkit

I'm new to swift development and stuck developing sattus bar application. Found some good toturials ([first](https://www.anaghsharma.com/blog/macos-menu-bar-app-with-swiftui/), [second](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app), [third](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fn4YZFFVq2E), [fourth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdPYBBAc2N4)), and in eash of them at some point authors inject AppDelegate to : App class, kinda:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct CaptureOneAppApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

And in tutorials similar code works just fine, but me getting compile-time error pointing row #5:

```
Type annotation missing in pattern
```

As I understand, compiler asks me to add some suffix with type definition, but i have no idea how it should look like and actually not sure if this is a correct way to solve the problem. So, what I'm doing wrong?

**UPD** AppDelegate.swift code:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the window and set the content view.
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

        //Initialising the status bar
        statusBar = StatusBarController.init()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

it's just copypasted from [first](https://www.anaghsharma.com/blog/macos-menu-bar-app-with-swiftui/)

Comment: @Asperi no, it just offers the same code I use, at least I cannot see difference

Comment: Well you can't use UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor for a macOS app, it's for iOS. try `@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor` instead.

Comment: Not the same - app delegate class should be explicitly declared. Show how you declare your `AppDelegate`. Here are some more examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/69055669/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348065/12299030.

Comment: guys thank you for your responses, the question is not matter anymore